# How to open a particular widget from android application ?

Tags: android, android-intent, widget

I want to open google sound search widget [image: sound search widget]( coming with google app) when the user press the image button , i want to know that , is there any way i can do that ? please help me

```
    ImageButton identifymusic =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.identifymusic);
    identifymusic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            // what to write here to open the widget
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this:

```
try {  
        Intent intent = new  Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);  
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,  
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);  
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "NOTICE TO USER");  
        startActivityForResult(intent, VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE);  
    } catch (Exception e) {  
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
```

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol 'VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE' @user7738848

Comment: add this to your code- private final int  VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE = 0x10;

Comment: i don't want to open this, i want to open a widget , google sound search (it is a tool to identify music inbuilt with google app)

Comment: If it's a google app,why not open it with its packname and classname?

Comment: How  to get the packname or classname ?

Comment: Ok if this is the package name 'com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox' how can i open this app. Please Edit your question

Comment: ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(packageName, className);  
  
        intent.setComponent(cn);  
        startActivity(intent);